# Use where and like in Ignited Datatables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable

how to implement Where and Like using Ignited Datatables for codeigniter while building query to get result.

Code i have tried is below:

```
$meter_id="12345";
$meter_id="'%".$meter_id."%'";
$this
    ->datatables
    ->select('Log_Name,Log_Creation_Date_Time,User_Name')
    ->from('Log_Data')
    ->where('Log_Name LIKE', $meter_id); //(Trying to Build LIke statement Here)
echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

**OR**

```
$meter_id="12345";   
$this
    ->datatables
    ->select('Log_Name,Log_Creation_Date_Time,User_Name')
    ->from('Log_Data')
    ->like('Log_Name', $meter_id);
echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

But above both code was not working.
i have also check the documentation of Ignited Datatables of Codeigniter but not found any example to bulid query with **LIKE** Keyword.

Query i have to build:

```
SELECT 
    Log_Name,
    Log_Creation_Date_Time, 
    User_Name 
FROM Log_Data
WHERE Log_Name LIKE '%12345%'
```

How could i will implement this?

Comment: You can just create your own sql and run it through the `$this->db->query()` method.

Comment: As i am using Ignited Datatables so using its library for displaying datatables , Using own query not giving me desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$meter_id="12345";   
$this->db->select('Log_Name,Log_Creation_Date_Time,User_Name')
         ->from('Log_Data')
         ->like('Log_Name', $meter_id);
$result = $this->db->get();
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$meter_id="12345";   
$this->db->select('Log_Name,Log_Creation_Date_Time,User_Name');
$this->db->like('Log_Name', $meter_id);
$query = $this->db->get('Log_Data');
$result = $query->result();
print_r($result);
```